# sourceURL in Firefox 24 doesn't seem to work

Tags: javascript, firefox, source-maps

I can't get `//# sourceURL` comments to work in Firefox 24.

Here is **test.html**:

```
<html>
<script src="test.js"></script>
```

And here is **test.js**:

```
document.write('<p>hello</p>');

//# sourceURL=one.js

var fn;

fn = eval("(function two() { console.log(1); })\n//# sourceURL=two.js");
fn.call();

fn = new Function([], "console.log(2);\n//# sourceURL=three.js");
fn.call();
```

If this were to work, I should see three files in the Firefox debugger: `one.js`, `two.js`, and `three.js`. However, the debugger shows me one file, `test.js`:

[image: firefox debugger]

Any clues as to what I've missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, sourceURL isn't implemented in Firefox yet.

See [Bug 904144](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=904144) (engine), [Bug 833744](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=833744) (frontend).

However, [Firebug seems to support it](http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/firebug/firebug-tip-label-dynamic-scripts-with-sourceurl-directive/).